# Error log faced while deploying ADF in Glassfish3

Tags: glassfish-3, oracle-adf

An application which developed with EJB, ADFFaces on JDeveloper 11.1.2.4 ide. Could be deployed on server at last, but many error lines out about .xsd files. How can i solve that issue?
brgds

```
...
File: file:/C:/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/generated/jsp/RestaurantAuto
mation/RestaurantAutomation_RestAutomationVC_webapp1_war/loader_962515257/oracle
/adfdt/model/dvt/schema/binding/gauge.xsd
[Error]: Line -1, Column -1: Invalid reference: ':ledStyleEnum'


[#|2013-11-08T17:27:25.647+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.cont
ainer.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=18;_ThreadName=admin-thread-pool-4848
(3);|WEB0671: Loading application [RestaurantAutomation#RestaurantAutomation_Res
tAutomationVC_webapp1.war] at [RestAutomation]|#]

[#|2013-11-08T17:27:26.068+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tool
s.admin.org.glassfish.deployment.admin|_ThreadID=18;_ThreadName=admin-thread-poo
l-4848(3);|RestaurantAutomation was successfully deployed in 75,528 milliseconds
.|#]
```

Comment: You followed the steps of deploying Oracle ADF Essentials on Glasshfish from here https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/deploying_oracle_adf_applications_to right

Comment: Just a thought, can you try to do the same steps with JDeveloper 11.1.2.3 instead of 11.1.2.4.

I believe the problem is the new version!